# Query data from excel file which is saved in sharepoint

Tags: sql, vba, connection, adodb

I need some help with the code to query and retrieve the data from the excel file saved on the Sharepoint server.

**The Code works fine here when i use local path**

```
Sub ConnectToSharePointExcel()
    ' Set your SharePoint path to the Excel file
    Dim sharePointPath As String
    Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim result1 As Object
    
    Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    sharePointPath = "C:\Users\" & Environ("username") & "\orgname\Base Tables\Master Data.xlsx"

    ' Create a connection string    
    conn.ConnectionString = _
            "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
            "Data Source=" & sharePointPath & _
            ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;"";"
        conn.Open

    ' Open the connection
    conn.Open connString
    
    sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM [Master_Ocean_New$]"
    Set result1 = conn.Execute(sqlQuery)

    ' Process the data or do something with the recordset

    ' Close the connection
    conn.Close
End Sub
```

**But following gives an error when i tried with sharepoint path. Able to establish a connection but unable to query.**

```
Sub ConnectToSharePointExcel()
    ' Set your SharePoint path to the Excel file
    Dim sharePointPath As String
    Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim result1 As Object
    
    Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

    sharePointPath = "\\sharepoint\sites\orgname\Shared%20Documents\Base%20Tables\Master%20Data.xlsx"

    ' Create a connection string
    Dim connString As String                 
    conn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
                 "WSS;HDR=YES;IMEX=2;" & _
                 "RetrieveIds=Yes;" & _
                 "DATABASE=" & sharePointPath & ";"
    conn.open
    
    Dim sqlQuery As String
    sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM [Master_Ocean_New$]"
    Set result1 = conn.Execute(sqlQuery)

    ' Process the data or do something with the recordset

    ' Close the connection
    conn.Close
End Sub
```

[Getting Error at line "Set result1 = conn.Execuute(sqlQuery)"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cFK9M.png)

Comment: Where do you `Open` the connection ?  I don't think there's any reliable way to convert a SharePoint HTTP[s] path to a network UNC path.   It would be great if there was...

Comment: I don't think you can convert a Sharepoint HTTPS path into a UNC path like that.  It may once have worked, but I'm pretty sure it no longer does.